# Increment Excel date every 30 days

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a excel sheet that I use to track projects and in one column I need to increment dates automatically.

I need to do the following. 
if today is 5/25/2018 I need the column to say 6/25/2018 and when its 6/25, I need the date to change to 7/25/18 automatically.

Comment: so not 30 days but one month?

Comment: yes one month. would it be possible to make the dates current?

Answer (score 1):

this will add one month to today:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,DAY(TODAY()))
```

and return a date.

If you only want to add a fixed 30 days regardless of month:

```
=TODAY()+30
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) I have one more question about this. So if I wanted to do this calculation from a previous date that has passed and increment by 30 so it because current. is that possible. The date I am starting with is 1/31/2018 and I want that incremented by a month, but to display the current date now which should be 5/31/18

Comment: so you want the day of this current month which is the same calendar day of a previous month?  what if this month was april with only 30 days, would we return `4/30/2018`,`5/1/2018`,or `N/A` since the day does not exist?

Comment: if there is 30 days then I would take 5/1 . A lot of this calculation was done manually in the past but now I want to make it a semi automatic to avoid mistakes. Thats why I have to start calculating from a previous date and not from today.

Comment: This really is a separate question and should be asked as one but: `=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(A1))`